# Shell script with options and argument - Update

Tags: shell, unix

Based on solutions below, I came up with this to accept either -q or -a as option, both with argument:

```
> #!/bin/bash
> 
> input_file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
> 
> while getopts ":qa:" opt; do   case $opt in
> 
>     q)
>       string="$OPTARG"
>       echo "org = $string"
>       grep -v '^>' "$input_file" | grep -x '.\{15,30\}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}' | perl -lane ' print ">dme" . $n++ . "_count=$F[1]\n$F[0]" if ($F[1] > 2) '      
>       ;;
> 
>     a)
>       string="$OPTARG"
>       echo "org = $string"
>       grep -v '^>' "$input_file" | grep -x '.\{15,30\}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}' | perl -lane ' print ">dme" . $n++ . "_count=$F[1]\n$F[0]" if ($F[1] > 2) '  
>       ;;
> 
>     \?)
>       echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
>       exit 1
>       ;;
>     :)
>       echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
>       exit 1
>       ;;   esac done
```

> ./script.sh -q "hsa" < test.txt > trial.txt

As advised, I took out option -m. Currently, I have the same instructions for options q and m, just for testing purposes. Option a works and yields the desired result. Option q does not throw an error but won't yield same result.

Also, I'd like to have the argument provided from the command line passed to the perl instructions, i.e. I'd like *dme* to be replaced with whatever is provided from the command line. Is there a way to do this? As it is now, the perl line runs fine.

Thanks!

Comment: `./help.sh < inputfile.txt -q -m one` why are you passing the content of the file? you can read the file in the script, if you pass the file path, `./help.sh path/to/inputfile.txt -q -m one`

Comment: @sarbbottam: Pipes and filters - many programs in a unix-like OS read from stdin and write to stdout

Comment: `< inputfile.txt` is not an argument to the script. It is redirecting the *standard input* of the script from `inputfile.txt`.

Comment: `sh` doesn't support `[[`. You need `bash`, `zsh`, etc. for that.

Comment: You also need to `shift` arguments away once you handle them if you want to keep using `$1` as the next unhandled argument.

Comment: Try `./help.sh -q -m one < inputfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use bash, that is change

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Added after the first comment:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file="${1:-/dev/stdin}"

#a and q do not have arguments and are interchangeable, option m accepts a three letter string
while getopts ":qam:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    q)
      echo "-q was triggered" #, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      #awk "$input_file" '{print $2, $1}' | perl -lane ' print ">one" . $n++ . "_count=$F[1]\n$F[0]" if ($F[1] > 2) ' > output1.txt
      ;;
    a)
      #perl -lane ' print ">one" . $n++ . "_count=$F[1]\n$F[0]" if ($F[1] > 2) ' < "$input_file" > output1.txt  
      echo "-a was triggered"
      ;;
    m)
      echo "-m was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      string="$OPTARG"
      if [ ${#string} = 3 ]; then 
        echo "string $string has length 3! good"
      else 
        echo "string $string should be of length 3!"
      exit
      fi
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Check that I did not forget anything from your original code. As far as i know you cannot call the the script with > between your options, but you can do this:

```
./script.sh -a -q -m "one" -X < test.html 
-a was triggered
-q was triggered
-m was triggered, Parameter: one
string one has length 3! good
Invalid option: -X
```

Notice that X is an invalid option.

**Edit** after Andy G updated his question:
You need to change getopts like this. Check on the docs if you want : or :: after q and a.

```
while getopts ":q:a:" opt; do
```

About the perl question: can you try this?

```
perl -lane ' print > "$string" . $n++ . "_count=$F[1]\n$F[0]" if ($F[1] > 2) '
```

Comment: Returns an error: Unrecognized switch: -q  (-h will show valid options)

Comment: Good, the [[ problem is gone. I updated my answer. NB: you cannot do

./help.sh < inputfile.txt -a -m one

but you can do:

./help.sh -a -m "one" < inputfile.txt

Comment: Thank you! This is pretty much the structure I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have a question. I would like to have either of a or q used at a time, not the two. Having only a and m in the option works fine. Having q and m throws and error: Unrecognized switch: -q  (-h will show valid options). Is there something I need to add? Thanks

Comment: If I understand your comment, what you want is that -a -m "one" is accepted, whereas -q -m "one" should throw an error. Is that correct?
In that case I would put some logic in the corresponding cases. For example, inside q) set option_q=1 and inside m) check if option_q exists and act accordingly: if [ -n "$option_q" ]; then ..  ; else echo "Unrecognized switch: -q "; fi
Give it a try and let me know if you have problems

Comment: Thanks for the response. In using the script, I want only two possible scenarios: ./script.sh -a -m "one" < test.html OR ./script.sh -q -m "one" < test.html to work. Anything else should throw an error. Currently, -a -m combination works great, however -q -m throws the error: Unrecognized switch: -q (-h will show valid options)

Comment: Andy, I (and other people) cannot help you if you do not show what code you are running. 
1) Using the code in my answer, which does not run awk nor perl, both  ./script.sh -a -m "one" < test.html AND  ./script.sh -q -m "one" < test.html work, that is no errors are thrown. What code are you running? Update your problem description. 
2) If you only want the two scenarios -a -m "one" OR -q -m "one" then -m is useless and you should remove it so that you can use -a "one" OR -q "one"

Comment: Hello, good job with the problem description, it is so much better. The problem with -q is that you need a colon (or two) in getopts after q:
while getopts ":q:a:" opt; do   ... 
Google what is the differrence between : and :: and make your choice